# Can I describe category of $F$-algebras by comma category?

Tags: category-theory

Recently, I'm learning $F$-algebra.

In wikipedia, it says that

> If $C$ is a category, and $F: C → C$ is an endofunctor of $C$, then an $F$-algebra is a tuple $(A, α)$, where $A$ is an object of $C$ and $α$ is a $C$-morphism $F(A) → A$. The object $A$ is called carrier of the algebra.
>
> A homomorphism from an $F$-algebra $(A, α)$ to an $F$-algebra $(B, β)$ is a
>   $C$-morphism $f: A→ B$ such that $f \circ α = β \circ F(f)$.

The category of $F$-algebras seems to be very similar to some kind of comma category. (One exception is that objects in comma category are triples, but objects in category of $F$-algebras are pairs).

Can I describe category of $F$-algebras by some kind of comma category?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F : \mathscr C \to \mathscr C$ be a functor. The comma category $F \downarrow \mathrm{Id}_{\mathscr C}$ has as objects triples $(A \in \mathscr C, A' \in \mathscr C', \alpha : FA \to A')$ and as morphisms from $(A \in \mathscr C, A' \in \mathscr C', \alpha : FA \to A')$ to $(B \in \mathscr C, B' \in \mathscr C', \beta : FB \to B')$ pairs $(f : A \to B, f' : A' \to B')$ such that the following diagram commutes.

[image: commutative square]

Here, we see the problem with expressing the category of $F$-algebras as a comma category: to restrict to the subcategory in which $A = A'$ and $B = B'$, we need to be able to choose the two objects from $\mathscr C$ in such a way that one depends on another, but in a comma category the choices are entirely independent. So, despite the seeming similarity between the two constructions, we cannot simply describe the category of $F$-algebras as a comma category.

(We can trivially describe the category of $F$-algebras as a comma category by considering $F\text{-}\mathbf{alg} \to \mathbb 1 \downarrow \mathrm{Id}_{\mathbb 1}$, but not in a way that takes advantage of the seeming similarity.)

Comment: You mentioned that "We can trivially describe the category of F-algebras as a comma category by considering F-alg→1↓Id1". Could you provide more information about this? What's the F-alg→1 mean? It is a functor?

Comment: Every category $\mathscr C$ is equivalent to the category $\mathscr C \to \mathbb 1 \downarrow \mathrm{Id}_{\mathbb 1}$, where $\mathbb 1$ is the terminal category, and $\mathscr C \to \mathbb 1$ is the unique functor to it. Objects of this comma category are triples $(c \in \mathscr C, * \in \mathbb 1, \mathrm{id}_*)$, i.e. objects of $\mathscr C$. So there's trivially a way in which we can consider the category of $F$-algebras as a comma category, but it's not enlightening.

Comment: That means F-alg is already the category of F-algebras, but we want to define F-alg, So it is not enlightening.